# Google Maps JavaScript API v3: Sorting Markers with Check Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, google-maps

Recently I built a map with custom markers (pins) and a sorting function to display each by type (Member, Supplier, Prospect, New Member).

The HTML (check boxes wired up with `sort()` function):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Supplier" onclick="sort()" id="switch2" />
          <label for="switch2">Suppliers</label>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var markersArray = [];

// data schema  ['Company Name',"Address",Latitude,Longitude,"Type"]
var data = [
  ['Company A',"Address",Latitude,Longitude,"Member"],
  ['Company B',"Address",Latitude,Longitude,"Supplier"],
  ['Company C',"Address",Latitude,Longitude,"Prospect"],
];

function initialize(data) {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -90)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Create the legend with content
  var legend = document.createElement('div');
      legend.id = 'legend';

  var content = [];
      content.push('<h3>Legend</h3>');
      content.push('<p><div class="legIcon"> <img src="pin_blue.png" alt="icon color" /> </div>Members</p>');
      content.push('<p><div class="legIcon"> <img src="pin_red.png" alt="icon color" /> </div>Suppliers</p>');
      content.push('<p><div class="legIcon"> <img src="pin_purple.png" alt="icon color" /> </div>New Members</p>');
      content.push('<p><div class="legIcon"> <img src="pin_green.png" alt="icon color" /> </div>Prospects</p>');

  legend.innerHTML = content.join('');
  legend.index = 1;

  // call the legend 
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);

  setMarkers(map, data);

}


function setMarkers(map, locations) {

  if (locations == undefined) {
    locations = data;
    return initialize(locations);
  }


  for (var i = locations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var company = locations[i],
          pinColor = '';

      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(company[2], company[3]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          shape: shape,
          title: company[0],
          type: company[4]
      });

      markersArray.push(marker);

      if ( marker.type === 'Member' ) { pinColor = 'blue' }
      else if ( marker.type === 'New') { pinColor = 'purple' }
      else if ( marker.type === 'Supplier') { pinColor = 'red' }
      else { pinColor = 'green' }  

      var image = {
        url: 'pin_' + pinColor + '.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 40)
      };
  };


}

// initialize map with empty array
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function (data) { initialize([]) });

// standalone functions
function clearOverlays () {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
     markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  } 
  markersArray.length = 0;
}

function resetPins () {
  clearOverlays();
}

// sort and collect with sliding buttons (checkboxes)
function sort () {

  var newData = [];

  // Pass the checkbox name to the function
  function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
    var checkboxesChecked = [];
    // loop over them all
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
       // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
       if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
       } 
       // clear the unchecked
       else {
          clearOverlays();
       }
    }
    // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
    return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
  }
  // call the boxes
  var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("switch");

  for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
      if ( d[4] === checkedBoxes[i] ) {
          newData.push(d);
        };
    });
  }

  if (newData.length > 0) { 
    return initialize(newData); 
  }
  else { 
    return initialize(data); 
  }  

}
```

I have not written a ton of vanilla JavaScript, so I would like some advice on how to clean this up.  The obvious: some loops count down, other up, there are various `if`/`else` statements that I feel may be superfluous, using `.forEach` inside a `for` loop.

Curiously, when the code runs, it skips the first element of data when assigning the custom pin as .png.  Why does this code not hit the first element in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's be frank - this code is a mess.

- A bunch of global variables and functions. That's never good. You should at least wrap these inside a container function.  Or better - turn it into an object.
- In the middle of the function definitions there's suddenly call to `google.maps.event.addDomListener()`. Don't mix the definitions and code that does something.  Bring all the initialization into one area.
- You knew already that the backwards for-loop is troublesome. You should have fixed it before submitting. Don't submit code that you know is poor.
- But when I look at the end of this for-loop... WTF? You are creating an `image` object and then you just throw it away. Is this code unfinished?
- For some reason the `getCheckedBoxes` function is defined inside `sort` function. Why?
- Inside `clearOverlays` you reset the `markersArray` by doing `markersArray.length = 0`.  That's not a proper way to reset an array. Instead just assign an empty array to replace the old one: `markersArray = []`.
- `resetPins` is just an alias to `clearOverlays`. Besides it's not used. Throw away the dead code.
- The `sort` function doesn't seem to be doing any sorting. Don't call it `sort` if it just switches groups of markers on and off.
- Too many other issues to mention...

Most importantly, try to care about your code. If you put your code out for others to see (by posting it here), try to first make it as good as you possibly can. Remove dead code. Fix the problems that you know about. Post a complete example, not half-finished one. Structure it so that it's as easy to read and understand as possible. Run it through JSHint and fix all the warnings, so you that people will not need to point out the mistakes that a stupid machine could have told you about.

Comment: Thanks Rene.  Yes, it is unfinished, I am refactoring now and appreciate your guidance on improving the code.  "Or better - turn it into an object." How would this look?

Comment: For Loops: I left both styles in to evoke discussion on which is most suitable.  After turning to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse its clear there is no clear answer.

Comment: By turning it into an object I meant writing it all in object-oriented style. You would basically turn it into a class, though as there are no real classes in JavaScript, that would mean creating a constructor function and adding the other functions as methods in its prototype. More on this topic: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Regarding the backwards loop: (1) Only optimize when there's an actual bottleneck, otherwise strive for most readable code; (2) don't rely on micro-benchmarks, measure the difference with your own actual code. Most likely this code doesn't really have to be blazing fast, so you're much better off using `Array.forEach()` and other methods that better convey the intention of your code.

Comment: "You are creating an image object and then you just throw it away."  Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Inside setMarkers() you define `var image` and then the loop and function end and the image variable is used nowhere.